# Необходимо считать координаты custom button, когда пользователь нажал и зажал кнопку

Tags: qt

Реализовал кнопку `custom button` с помощью `stylesheets`, теперь необходимо считать координаты кнопки когда пользователь нажал и зажал для дальнейшего перемещения кнопки. 
Пробовал считывать с помощью `QMouseEvent *eventMove->global x()`, но проблема в том, что считывание идет корректно пока пользователь не зажал кнопку. 
Вариант с `mouse press` тоже отпадает так как считывание идет, когда пользователь уже отпустил кнопку это уже не так важно.

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понятна задача. По mousePressEvent обрабатываем событие нажатия, по mouseReleaseEvent - отпускания кнопки.

> Пробовал считывать с помощью QMouseEvent *eventMove->global x(), но проблема в том, что считывание идет корректно пока пользователь не зажал кнопку.

по какому событию считываете?

> Вариант с mouse press тоже отпадает так как считывание идет, когда пользователь уже отпустил кнопку это уже не так важно.

неправда, событие наступает сразу по mousePressEvent, до того как пользователь отпустил кнопку

Comment: если на пустом widget то да, попробуй создать кнопку через дизайнер или программно а потому считать координаты местоположения мыши и в ответ не получишь ничего.

Comment: создается ощущение что кнопка имеет свой layout правда как к нему достучаться не совсем понятно.